# Failed to release mocks : Getting this error while testing firebase insertion function in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mockito, junit4

I have a FirebaseRepository file that contains a method addDonor that allows user to add Donor object to firebase.

```
package com.example.carepro
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class FirebaseRepository(): IFirebaseRepository {

    private val donorsDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Donors")

    @Volatile private var INSTANCE: FirebaseRepository ?= null

    fun getInstance(): FirebaseRepository{

        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
            val instance = FirebaseRepository()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }

    }

    // inserting donor into database
    override fun addDonor(donor: Donor) : String {

        val newMessageId = donorsDatabaseReference.push().key
        var msg= ""

        donorsDatabaseReference.child(newMessageId!!).setValue(donor).addOnSuccessListener {
            msg="Success"

        }.addOnFailureListener{
            msg="Failure"
        }
        return msg
    }
}
```

The donor class file is:

```
class Donor(var contact_id: String ?= null,
            var name: String ?= null,
            var blood_group: String ?= null,
            var location: String ?= null,
            var age: Int ?= null,
            var gender: String ?= null,
            ){

    fun addDonor(){
        val repository: IFirebaseRepository
        repository = FirebaseRepository().getInstance()
        repository.addDonor(this)
    }
}
```

To test the function addDonor, I have created a testClass in the androidtest folder. I am using Junit4 and mockito for testing.
This is my test class:

```
package com.example.carepro

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

class FirebaseRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var donorsDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference

    @Mock
    private lateinit var firebaseRepository: FirebaseRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        firebaseRepository = FirebaseRepository()
    }

    @Test
    fun addDonor() {
        `when`(donorsDatabaseReference.push()).thenReturn(mock(DatabaseReference::class.java))
        `when`(donorsDatabaseReference.push().key).thenReturn("fakeKey")

        val donor = Donor("0309-0078601", "Jack", "B+", "San Francisco", 21,"Male")

        val statusMessage = firebaseRepository.addDonor(donor)

        verify(donorsDatabaseReference).push()
        verify(donorsDatabaseReference.child("fakeKey")).setValue(donor)

        assertEquals("Success", statusMessage)
    }
}
```

Dependencies I have used are:

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2'
```

The error I am getting is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Failed to release mocks

This should not happen unless you are using a third-part mock maker
at com.example.carepro.FirebaseRepositoryTest.setUp(FirebaseRepositoryTest.kt:21)
... 26 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy6.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:33)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:250)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:83)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1954)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:66)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:27)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:24)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:45)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:73)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:48)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:82)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:100)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@b30560b
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:57)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:65)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:50)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:20)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getAnnotationEngine(Plugins.java:67)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.GlobalConfiguration.tryGetPluginAnnotationEngine(GlobalConfiguration.java:57)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:81)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:52)
... 36 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException:
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if you are trying to run this mock maker on Android which does not support the instrumentation API.

IMPORTANT INFORMATION FOR ANDROID USERS:

The regular Byte Buddy mock makers cannot generate code on an Android VM!
To resolve this, please use the 'mockito-android' dependency for your application:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-android

Java               : 0.9
JVM vendor name    : The Android Project
JVM vendor version : 2.1.0
JVM name           : Dalvik
JVM version        : 0.9
JVM info           : null
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 5.15.41-android13-8-00055-g4f5025129fe8-ab8949913

at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:246)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$ProcessProvider$ForCurrentVm$ForLegacyVm.resolve(ByteBuddyAgent.java:1302)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$ProcessProvider$ForCurrentVm.resolve(ByteBuddyAgent.java:1285)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:586)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:538)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:515)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:117)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~4dmrrQLYdCohk5d5BT9SIw==/com.example.carepro.test-klhcodpFgBmcaAXRRBUSfQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~sLYC6Iq0LDLQa6mVBaj5bg==/com.example.carepro-BlbPivGxB50L5OxawEAqjg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~4dmrrQLYdCohk5d5BT9SIw==/com.example.carepro.test-klhcodpFgBmcaAXRRBUSfQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~sLYC6Iq0LDLQa6mVBaj5bg==/com.example.carepro-BlbPivGxB50L5OxawEAqjg==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 46 more
```

I have tried adding mock-maker-inline in the androidTest\resources\mockitoExtensions\org.mockito.plugins.MocKMaker file `

I have also tried using the latest version of the dependencies

I also tried adding this:

```
androidTestImplementation ('org.mockito:mockito-android:3.11.2') {
        exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy', module: 'byte-buddy'
        exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy', module: 'byte-buddy-android'
    }
```

but the error message remains the same. What could be the issue? Can someone please help me solve the problem I am facing?
(I am using Android Studio : In case some settings are to be changed for it)